# Pair data of the list with it last value

Tags: python, list

How to pair the value of the list with the last value of the same list without including its last value ??

```
[1,2,3,4,5,10]

[6,7,8,9,10,11]

[12,13,14,15,16,17]
```

expected output :

```
[1,10], [2,10], [3,10], [4,10], [5,10]
[6,11], [7,11], [8,11], [9,11], [10,11]
[12,17], [13,17], [14,17], [15,17], [16,17]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using `list slicing`.

**Ex:**

```
lst = [[1,2,3,4,5,10], [6,7,8,9,10,11], [12,13,14,15,16,17]]
for i in lst:
    print([[j, i[-1]] for j in i[:-1]])
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10], [4, 10], [5, 10]]
[[6, 11], [7, 11], [8, 11], [9, 11], [10, 11]]
[[12, 17], [13, 17], [14, 17], [15, 17], [16, 17]]
```

---

Or using `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product

lst = [[1,2,3,4,5,10], [6,7,8,9,10,11], [12,13,14,15,16,17]]
for i in lst:
    print(list(product(i[:-1], [i[-1]])))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,10]
x_new = [[i,x[-1]] for i in x[:-1]]
print(x_new)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10], [4, 10], [5, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use list comprehension:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,10]
[[i, l[-1]] for i in l[:-1]]
```

or you can use `itertools.cycle`

```
from itertools import cycle

[[i, j] for i, j in zip(l, cycle(l[-1:]))]
```

output:

```
[[1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10], [4, 10], [5, 10], [10, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

use `zip`

```
>>>
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,10]
>>> x = [a[-1]]*len(a) #get last item, add to list, multiply by len of 'a' list.
>>> z = zip(a,x)
>>>output = []
>>> for x,y in zip(a,x):
...    output.append([x,y])
...
>>> output
[[1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10], [4, 10], [5, 10], [10, 10]]
```